# jmeter is not able to load content of homepage after login

Tags: jmeter

`jmeter` is not able to load web page after login page redirect to default homepage.

After starting recording with webpage url, it will redirect to login page and after submitting credentials, it will redirect to default homepage. `jmeter` is able to redirect to default homepage but not able to load its content. It looks like it is in loading state.

During recording i have unchecked `FOLLOW REDIRECT` and `REDIRECT AUTOMATICALLY`
if we open homepage normally , without `jmeter` recording, it is loading perfectly.

Comment: Try having Redirect Automatically disabled, and Follow Redirects enabled.

Comment: If you want to retrieve all content, check `Retrieve All Embedded Resources`.

Comment: @Adnan - i have already checked Retrieve All Embedded Resource and got same issue .

Comment: @IvanMarkovic- Redirect Automatically is already disabled

Answer (score 2):

With the given information, I can't pinpoint the issue. But following is the useful information for debugging:

1. Understand http traffic i.e., getting generated when using the application. To capture the traffic, you can use browser builtin options (Chrome,IE and Firefox -F12-Networks tab) or wireshark, fidler etc. Delete the cache before you start.
2. Find the source/initiator of the request which loads the content of the user logged in.

Once you find the trigger/source point of the request:

a. If source is html file, then Jmeter will send the requests for embedded resources only if "Retrieve All Embedded Resource" is **enabled**.

b. If source is other than html, such as .js (in case of ajax requests), .css, then it is LIMITATION in jmeter, which wont parse these files to check for the requests to send, even if "Retrieve All Embedded Resource" is enabled.

So, if the source of the request (which loads content) is .js or .css, then we should explicitly add that request as a sampler (take care of other things, such as adding HTTP Cookie Manager, Header Manager etc., in case the request demands).

Meanwhile, please provide following information:

1. Does all http requests are recorded? Match with browser (F12) Networks tab.
   If yes, what is the status of those requests, when replayed? Check using **View Results Tree Listener**.
2. If only parent/source request is recorded, then look whether it is sending the request/s (which loads the content) using **View Results Tree Listener**.

Comment: @Naveen-  Thanks for your Input. Retrieve All Embedded Resource" is already enabled. for rest ou your queries i will reply on Monday once i check them using view result tree. btw how we add request as sampler during recording, because during recording i just use the flow of action to record. how can i use sampler in between recording and still records next action.
like here after login to launch to homepage

Comment: we can't add samplers during recording. It is after recording, we need to add all required/missing http requests which are not sent (using the option "retrieve all Embeded resources"  by default). To add sampler, right click on the group, Add -> Sampler -> Http Request. Fill all the fields that are required like, server host, path, body etc. You may be required to add HTTP header manager and HTTP cookie manager. References: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request. I strongly suggest to go though Jmeter built-in help using "Help" (right click on the component)